# I get an error in CNN optimization (learning) implemented by keras, but I do not know the solution

Tags: python, deep-learning

An error occurred while creating the convolutional layer of the CNN model.
I do not know the cause of the error and how to handle it. I'm in the process of implementing CNN using keras and cifar10 for machine learning with Python 3.5.

I get the following error in the learning phase:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_46 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

It does not work well with reshaping the array of labels (y_train).

```py
#import
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#get data
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()


#Image normalization
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0



#Build a CNN mode

def CNN_model():
    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    #1st convolutional layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(96, 11, strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', activation='relu', bias_initializer='ones', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last'))

    #2nd convolutional layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 2, strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', activation='relu', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last'))

    #3rd layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    #4th Softmax layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    #compile
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

#Summary
model = CNN_model()
model.summary()
```

[image]

```py
#Fitting
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.25, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here lies in your target aka `y_train`. Yours is probably a 1 x n_samples long vector with 10 different lables in. The way Keras needs it is in a One-Hot-Encoded way. You can do this by:

```py
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It was possible to implement ! Thank you !

Comment: Happy to help! If it answered your question you can mark it as answered :)

Comment: I have chosen your solution as the best answer !